# Stopping Scrolling and Bounce on UIWebView on xCode6 / iOS-8

Tags: javascript, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I've created a game using CSS/JS/HTML and the launch page is a HTML document running inside a UIWebView.. however.. when the app runs either in a simulator or on a device (iphone4/5) the screen scrolls down and bounces.. on an iPad this isn't the case, its fine.

I've read quite a few answers here on S/O but none of them cover xcode6 / iOS8

Any advice etc would be great, thanks..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

set delegate for webview

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
        [webView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(webview.frame.size.width, webview.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
       // or webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
}
```

hopo this help!!